# don't not showing up properly html (Fix with php?)

Tags: php, html

hey, for some reason instead of don't showing up as

```
don't
```

it's showing up as

```
don&amp;# ;t
```

any ideas on how i can convert the

```
&amp;# ;
```

into the '  using php?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you figure out why it's happening. Treat the illness, not the symptoms.

Comment: Looks like double escaping and a decimals eating gremlin in your code.

Comment: alright thanks guys :) I'll try figuring out what's causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a simple `str_replace("&amp;# ;", "'", $string)`, though it would be far, far better to find out why this odd issue is occuring in the first place.